# database_xml_deadlock_report or xml_deadlock_report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, extended-events

Is `[database_xml_deadlock_report]` the same as `[xml_deadlock_report]` just with extra fields?

I'm creating a basic deadlock and blocking capture and see both.  Most examples online show `[xml_deadlock_report]`, but `[database_xml_deadlock_report]` has extra fields that may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are essentially the same thing. **database_xml_deadlock_report** was introduced to provide a method for retrieving deadlocks for Azure SQL Databases by scoping the deadlock event to the victim database and allowing users to create database scoped extended events sessions.

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) for more information. Basically, the XML Report event field should return the same information and that is where the important data is. The other three fields (database_name, server_name and deadlock_cycle_id) are obtainable from within the XML report or from the global fields.

You can basically use either one.